# Add songs to Jquery JAudio playlist without refreshing player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a custom mp3 player for a entertainment web site and i need to add songs continuously even when playing a song. to do that i'm using this function.

```
var temp = [];
var tempObj = [];

function popUp(file,thumb,trackName,trackArtist,trackAlbum) {

    var validate = true;
    if (temp.length>0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
            if (temp[x]['trackName'] == trackName) {
                validate = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (validate==true){

        // Save data to object
        tempObj = { file: file, thumb: thumb, trackName: trackName, trackArtist: trackArtist, trackAlbum: trackAlbum };
        temp.push(tempObj); // push object to existing array
        $("#player").jAudio({playlist: temp});

    }
}
```

Problem is that to add songs to player we need to run that "jAudio()" function. because of that every time "popUp()" function called it calling the "jAudio()" function. if any one have a solution, please shear it..

This is the JAudio API.

```
!function (t) {
    function i(i, a) {
        this.settings = t.extend(!0, r, a), this.$context = i, this.domAudio = this.$context.find("audio")[0], this.$domPlaylist = this.$context.find(".jAudio--playlist"), this.$domControls = this.$context.find(".jAudio--controls"), this.$domVolumeBar = this.$context.find(".jAudio--volume"), this.$domDetails = this.$context.find(".jAudio--details"), this.$domStatusBar = this.$context.find(".jAudio--status-bar"), this.$domProgressBar = this.$context.find(".jAudio--progress-bar-wrapper"), this.$domTime = this.$context.find(".jAudio--time"), this.$domElapsedTime = this.$context.find(".jAudio--time-elapsed"), this.$domTotalTime = this.$context.find(".jAudio--time-total"), this.$domThumb = this.$context.find(".jAudio--thumb"), this.currentState = "pause", this.currentTrack = this.settings.defaultTrack, this.timer = void 0, this.init()
    }

    function a(t, i) {
        for (var t = String(t); t.length < i;)t = "0" + t;
        return t
    }

    var e = "jAudio", r = {
        playlist: [],
        defaultAlbum: void 0,
        defaultArtist: void 0,
        defaultTrack: 0,
        autoPlay: !1,
        debug: !1
    };
    i.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var t = this;
            t.renderPlaylist(), t.preLoadTrack(), t.highlightTrack(), t.updateTotalTime(), t.events(), t.debug(), t.domAudio.volume = .2
        }, play: function () {
            var t = this, i = t.$domControls.find("#btn-play");
            t.currentState = "play", t.domAudio.play(), clearInterval(t.timer), t.timer = setInterval(t.run.bind(t), 50), i.data("action", "pause"), i.attr("id", "btn-pause"), i.toggleClass("active")
        }, pause: function () {
            var t = this, i = t.$domControls.find("#btn-pause");
            t.domAudio.pause(), clearInterval(t.timer), t.currentState = "pause", i.data("action", "play"), i.attr("id", "btn-play"), i.toggleClass("active")
        }, stop: function () {
            var t = this;
            t.domAudio.pause(), t.domAudio.currentTime = 0, t.animateProgressBarPosition(), clearInterval(t.timer), t.updateElapsedTime(), t.currentState = "stop"
        }, prev: function () {
            var t, i = this;
            t = 0 === i.currentTrack ? i.settings.playlist.length - 1 : i.currentTrack - 1, i.changeTrack(t)
        }, next: function () {
            var t, i = this;
            t = i.currentTrack === i.settings.playlist.length - 1 ? 0 : i.currentTrack + 1, i.changeTrack(t)
        }, preLoadTrack: function () {
            var t = this;
            t.changeTrack(t.settings.defaultTrack), t.settings.autoPlay && t.play()
        }, changeTrack: function (t) {
            var i = this;
            i.currentTrack = t, i.domAudio.src = i.settings.playlist[t].file, i.highlightTrack(), i.updateThumb(), i.renderDetails(), "play" === i.currentState && i.play()
        }, events: function () {
            var i = this;
            i.$domControls.on("click", "button", function () {
                var a = t(this).data("action");
                switch (a) {
                    case"prev":
                        i.prev.call(i);
                        break;
                    case"next":
                        i.next.call(i);
                        break;
                    case"pause":
                        i.pause.call(i);
                        break;
                    case"stop":
                        i.stop.call(i);
                        break;
                    case"play":
                        i.play.call(i)
                }
            }), i.$domPlaylist.on("click", ".jAudio--playlist-item", function () {
                var a = t(this), e = (a.data("track"), a.index());
                i.currentTrack !== e && i.changeTrack(e)
            }), i.$domProgressBar.on("click", function (t) {
                i.updateProgressBar(t), i.updateElapsedTime()
            }), t(i.domAudio).on("loadedmetadata", function () {
                i.animateProgressBarPosition.call(i), i.updateElapsedTime.call(i), i.updateTotalTime.call(i)
            })
        }, getAudioSeconds: function (t) {
            var t = t % 60;
            return t = a(Math.floor(t), 2), t = 60 > t ? t : "00"
        }, getAudioMinutes: function (t) {
            var t = t / 60;
            return t = a(Math.floor(t), 2), t = 60 > t ? t : "00"
        }, highlightTrack: function () {
            var t = this, i = t.$domPlaylist.children(), a = "active";
            i.removeClass(a), i.eq(t.currentTrack).addClass(a)
        }, renderDetails: function () {
            var t = this, i = t.settings.playlist[t.currentTrack], a = (i.file, i.thumb, i.trackName), e = i.trackArtist, r = (i.trackAlbum, "");
            r += "<p>", r += "<span>" + a + "</span>", r += "<span>" + e + "</span>", r += "</p>", t.$domDetails.html(r)
        }, renderPlaylist: function () {
            var i = this, a = "";
            t.each(i.settings.playlist, function (t, i) {
                {
                    var e = i.file, r = i.thumb, o = i.trackName, s = i.trackArtist;
                    i.trackAlbum
                }
                trackDuration = "00:00", a += "<div class='jAudio--playlist-item' data-track='" + e + "'>", a += "<div class='jAudio--playlist-thumb'><img src='" + r + "'></div>", a += "<div class='jAudio--playlist-meta-text'>", a += "<h4>" + o + "</h4>", a += "<p>" + s + "</p>", a += "</div>", a += "</div>"
            }), i.$domPlaylist.html(a)
        }, run: function () {
            var t = this;
            t.animateProgressBarPosition(), t.updateElapsedTime(), t.domAudio.ended && t.next()
        }, animateProgressBarPosition: function () {
            var t = this, i = 100 * t.domAudio.currentTime / t.domAudio.duration + "%", a = {width: i};
            t.$domProgressBar.children().eq(0).css(a)
        }, updateProgressBar: function (t) {
            var i, a, e, r = this;
            t.offsetX && (i = t.offsetX), void 0 === i && t.layerX && (i = t.layerX), a = i / r.$domProgressBar.width(), e = r.domAudio.duration * a, r.domAudio.currentTime = e, r.animateProgressBarPosition()
        }, updateElapsedTime: function () {
            var t = this, i = t.domAudio.currentTime, a = t.getAudioMinutes(i), e = t.getAudioSeconds(i), r = a + ":" + e;
            t.$domElapsedTime.text(r)
        }, updateTotalTime: function () {
            var t = this, i = t.domAudio.duration, a = t.getAudioMinutes(i), e = t.getAudioSeconds(i), r = a + ":" + e;
            t.$domTotalTime.text(r)
        }, updateThumb: function () {
            var t = this, i = t.settings.playlist[t.currentTrack].thumb, a = {"background-image": "url(" + i + ")"};
            t.$domThumb.css(a)
        }, debug: function () {
            var t = this;
            t.settings.debug && console.log(t)
        }
    }, t.fn[e] = function (a) {
        var e = function () {
            return new i(t(this), a)
        };
        t(this).each(e)
    }
}(jQuery);

// initialize
(function () {


}());
```

Comment: Does it not provide any api to add track in the playlist?

Comment: No.. is there any way that we could done it with this function..

Comment: You must have to add a new prototype function in the plugin code itself that can re-render your playlist. And then call that function on your plugin instance.

Comment: @Manish i added API code for your information. can you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but if you are willing to go a little nasty, I have a working workaround. Forgive me for the nasty approach, in the end though - it works.

We are gonna make use of **window** here to use as a global scope across the functions.

```
init: function()
{
  var self = this;
  self.renderPlaylist();
  self.preLoadTrack();
  self.highlightTrack();
  self.updateTotalTime();
  self.events();
  self.debug();
  self.domAudio.volume = 0.05;
  window.jAudioCore = self; // This line returns the self
},
```

Now you can change the playlist accordingly, anytime, just by changing **window.playlist** global variable, *everywhere in the code*.

```
    renderPlaylist: function()
{
  var self = this,
      template = "";


  $.each(window.playlist, function(i, a) //added window.playlist as the parameter
```

Your **renderPlaylist** function should look the one above.

To test this here's a simple code for you to use :

```
(function(){
window.playlist = [
      {
        file: "http://192.168.1.99:5000/mpeg",
        thumb: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kd57YHWqrsI/mqdefault.jpg",
        trackName: "Carnival Of Rust",
        trackArtist: "Poets Of The Fall",
        trackAlbum: "Single",
        trackDuration:"04:06",
      },
      {
        file: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/mpeg",
        thumb: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kd57YHWqrsI/mqdefault.jpg",
        trackName: "Carnival Of Rust",
        trackArtist: "Poets Of The Fall",
        trackAlbum: "Single",
        trackDuration:"04:06",
      }
  ];

  var t = {
    playlist: [], // this is no longer needed, you can remove it from the source code later
    debug:true
  }
  $(".jAudio").jAudio(t);
    setTimeout(function(){
    window.playlist.push({
        file: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/mpeg",
        thumb: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kd57YHWqrsI/mqdefault.jpg",
        trackName: "Carnival Of Rust",
        trackArtist: "Poets Of The Fall",
        trackAlbum: "Single",
        trackDuration:"04:06",
      });
       window.jAudioCore.renderPlaylist(); // renders the playlists
       window.jAudioCore.preLoadTrack(); // will preload the current track
       window.jAudioCore.highlightTrack(); // will highlight in the css

    },3000);

})();
```

As I said, in the end, it works dynamically without refresh. There might be some underlying bugs, I couldn't test much on this. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I'm abandon that project long time ago. Hench i can's check this is working or not.